# Google Cloud Build Time Out after 10 mins

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-build

[image]

[image]

I have a Google Cloud Build build that times out after 10 min. The build status is set to "Build failed (timeout)" and I'm okay with it taking longer than 10 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can give time out manually as below using YAML :

In cloudbuild.yaml you have to add something like [timeout](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config-file-schema#timeout_2): 1200s

E.g.

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: [ 'build', '-t', 'gcr.io/[PRODUCT_ID]/[CONTAINER_IMAGE]', '.' ]
images: 
- 'gcr.io/[PRODUCT_ID]/[CONTAINER_IMAGE]'
timeout: 1200s
```

**Note** : The maximum value that can be applied to timeout is 24 hours. The timeout must be specified in seconds with up to nine fractional digits, terminated by 's'. Example: "3.5s" .
If timeout is not set, a default timeout of 10 minutes will apply to the build.

See the full definition of a [Build Resource](https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.builds#resource-build)  and [configuring the deployment](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-appengine#configuring_the_deployment) in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 10 minutes is the default timeout [as documented](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.builds#resource-build).

Just set the timeout field for the build to a longer value (e.g. "3600s" for an hour) when you create the build.